# Прошу пояснить, что означает предлог ПО в следующем предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги, смысл

Я не понимаю следующее предложение:

> Наниматель, должен внести наймодателю арендную плату за месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой в размере по 10т.р.

Предложение означает, что нанимателю надо заплатить за месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой- 10т.р. ? Или данное предложение означает, что нанимателю надо заплатить за месяц пользования жилым помещением- 10т.р., за месяц пользования  мебелью — 10т.р. и за месяц пользования бытовой техникой- 10т.р. ?

Comment: Если принять во внимание, что в предложении стоит совершенно безграмотная запятая, то можно исходить из того, что построено предложение безграмотно, поэтому я бы интерпретировал его как "за все вместе 10 тысяч в месяц".

Comment: Видимо, "наниматель" здесь - обращение, причём на "ты", как можно заключить из единственного числа глагола :) Из совершенного вида глагола следует, что за 1 месяц, но за каждый вид услуг - по 10 тысяч (всего - 30).

Answer (score 2):

1. Формулировка не подлежит однозначному осмыслению. Все наши попытки не просто юридически ничтожны, они даже не будут имитировать подходы, которыми оперируют юристы. Скорее всего договор сам по себе следуют признать ничтожным из-за невозможности однозначной трактовки.
2. Исходя из здравого смысла (имеющего здесь силу только в рамках лингвистических разговоров, но никак не юридических) предлог "по" здесь может трактоваться только в одном значении -

> 5. Употр. при указании количества кого-, чего-л., обозначаемого
>      количественными числительными и количественными словами, а также
>      собирательными числительными, которое приходится при распределении
>      кого-, чего-л. Идти в колонне по двое. Заплатить за работу по десять
>      рублей. Автобусы по сорок сидячих мест. Купюры по сто рублей. Собрать
>      по тридцать центнеров зерна с гектара.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BF%D0%BE&all=x

То есть тут за каждую из перечисленных позиций. Всего 30 000. Аналогично и последующее "далее наниматель должен вносить арендную плату ежемесячно", по 30 000 в месяц. Арендная плата - как можно судить из первого случая - это сумма, складывающаяся из трех составляющих. То есть и далее сумма - 30 000.

> Вне контекста можно обратить внимание на то, что слово "внести"
>   предполагает одноразовое действие,

Да, "внести" - глагол совершенного вида и поэтому однократный, это и вне контекста и внутри него. Однако это никак не распространяется на следующую фразу, где однозначно внесение предполагается регулярным.

> Строго говоря, нужно объявить, что написанное не соответствует
>   правилам русского языка, что препятствует пониманию текста.

Видимо, в тексте проскочило лишнее "по" (в первом случае) - с какого-то шаблона делали.
Но читать надо было раньше, при подписании.

Answer (score 1):

Одним из значений предлога ПО является **распределительное значение**: по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый предмет. Или другой вариант: по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый месяц.

Но **по смыслу** речь скорее идет о ежемесячной плате за все услуги, только предложение составлено некорректно, и его надо исправить:

Наниматель должен внести наймодателю арендную плату за пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой **в размере 10 тысяч рублей в месяц.**

Comment: Жасмин. Огромное спасибо!!! К сожалению уже ни чего не исправить((( И сейчас требуется разобраться, что означает, то что есть(((  В тексте месяц указан в единственном числе. Жасмин. Как Вы считаете какой из указанных Вами вариантов правильный ? по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый предмет ? Или по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый месяц ?

Comment: Я думаю так. Если речь идет об одном месяце, то по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый предмет (здесь как бы расписано, за какие удобства надо платить).

Comment: Жасмин. Огромное спасибо! Вы очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

> Наниматель, должен внести наймодателю арендную плату за месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой в размере по 10т.р.

Предложение составлено так, что допускает различные толкования: "по 10 тысяч рублей за (каждый) месяц пользования всем перечисленным" или "за пользование жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой — по 10 тысяч рублей (за каждый вид)"

Все зависит от контекста. Вне контекста можно обратить внимание на то, что  слово "внести" предполагает одноразовое действие, то есть наниматель должен заплатить только один раз, только за один месяц, но по 10 тысяч рублей за каждый вид услуг.

Это формально. А исходя из жизненного опыта, такая ситуация кажется маловероятной (договор составлен на один месяц, общая сумма оплаты не указана, зато указаны ее составляющие).

Если Вам известно, что договор не на месяц, а на более длительный срок, то, исходя из здравого смысла, нужно признать, что **наниматель должен вносить наймодателю арендную плату за пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой в размере 10 тысяч рублей в месяц.**

Comment: М_Г. Огромное спасибо!  В договоре написано - Далее наниматель должен вносить арендную плату ежемесячно. - В сочетании с первым предложением что это означает? По 10тр в месяц ? Или по 30тр в месяц?

Comment: Формально говоря, истолковать такой договор однозначно невозможно. Исходя из здравого смысла — по 10 тысяч рублей в месяц.

Comment: А если исходить из лексики русского языка, то как толкуется написанное ?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не имеет ответа. Строго говоря, нужно объявить, что написанное не соответствует правилам русского языка, что препятствует пониманию текста. Остается только исходить из здравого смысла. – М_Г 3 часа назад

Comment: Огромное спасибо!!! Мне очень важно Ваше мнение.       Может быть есть ещё мнения специалистов и профессионалов???