# Значение предлога "по"

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография

> Наниматель, должен внести наймодателю арендную плату за первый месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой по 10т.р. Далее арендная плата вносится в течении года до 1 числа каждого месяца.

Общая арендная плата 10 000 руб в месяц или 30 000 руб в месяц ?

Comment: Не нужно снова задавать тот же самый вопрос.

Comment: Здесь контекст немного другой, это влияет на понимание фразы.

Comment: Вы можете обратиться в лингвистическую экспертизу.

Comment: Интересно, сколько стоит такая экспертиза?

Comment: Думаю, все зависит от органа, который будет выполнять. А также от сложности, объема.

Comment: @М_Г экспертиза дорогая (счет на десятки тысяч), но она тут совершенно бессмысленна. Вопрос совершенно непонятен Вернее непонятно, откуда тут может быть сомнения..

Comment: @Мимоходов Если у Вас нет сомнения, то стоит изложить Ваше мнение и помочь Ире.

Comment: @М_Г У меня нет сомнений. Я имел ввиду, что экспертиза не возьмется за решение подобным образом сформулированного вопроса. А мнение своё я изложил в "дубликате" вопроса.  https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/440473

Comment: А, да. Самая качественная экспертиза на мой взгляд - это ГЛЭДИС. http://rusexpert.ru/. Но, повторюсь, не стоит туда обращаться с подобным образом сформулированными вопросами. Некорректная постановка.

Comment: Запятая, конечно, это что-то...

Answer (score 0):

> Наниматель, должен внести наймодателю арендную плату за первый месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой по 10т.р. Далее арендная плата вносится до 1 числа каждого месяца.

Хотя предложение составлено неудачно, но у меня нет сомнений, что с точки зрения правил русского языка в данном контексте *по* относится к объектам, поступающим в пользование (жилое помещение, мебель, бытовая техника). Таким образом, общая арендная плата за первый месяц составит 30 000 руб. В первом предложении явно указано что речь идет именно об  арендной плате за **первый** месяц. Арендная плата за остальные месяцы не оговорена.

Примечание. То, что я написал, — не более чем мое субъективное мнение. Разумеется, официально вопрос должен решаться с привлечением сертифицированных экспертов.

Comment: Вопрос явно не праздный и, может, весьма болезненный, поэтому я бы не утверждал что-то категорично, не имея перед глазами полного текста контракта. И вообще, посоветовал бы обратиться к юристам. Уверенно можно (и нужно) сказать лишь, что первая запятая поставлена ошибочно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваши мнения!!! К сожалению юристы специализируются на юриспруденции и не сильны в лингвистике(((

Comment: Юристы умеют составлять договоры так, чтобы добиться однозначного понимания текста. В данном случае юрист обязательно указал бы полную сумму арендной платы, например: за первый месяц пользования жилым помещением, мебелью и бытовой техникой — по 10 тыс. руб. за каждый вид, всего 30 тыс. руб.

Comment: М_Г. Вы правы! Однако данный договор уже заключён(((  И я пытаюсь понять что там написано(((

Comment: Но Вы показали две версии в двух разных вопросах. Это наводит на мысль, что это не окончательный вариант.

Comment: Я передала в вопросе смысл.